# Convert XSSFSheet to List<Pojo> with poi apache in Java

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

Is there any way we can covert the XSSFSheet to the list of POJO.
The number of rows will result in the size of ArrayList.
Here is the below sheet I have.

[image]

And here is the POJO -

```
    public class Sprint {

       String name;
       Integer age;
       String phone;

    // getter and setters
   }
```

And here is function -

```
public String singleFileUpload(FileBucket fileBucket) throws IOException {

            MultipartFile multipartFile = fileBucket.getFile();
            FileCopyUtils.copy(fileBucket.getFile().getBytes(), new File(UPLOAD_LOCATION + fileBucket.getFile().getOriginalFilename()));
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(multipartFile.getInputStream());
             XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
             List<Sprint> sprint= new ArrayList();

            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {   
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                // here I want to convert sheet to list of POJO

                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch (cell.getCellType())
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }           
            return "success";
        }
```

Please help!. 
Thanks in advance.